# How to return an object that is the result of overwritten object elements

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

How to return an object that is the result of overwritten object elements

I want to return only those elements that firstObject has overwritten in secondObject using Ecmascript6

```
var firstObject = {
  one: 1,
  four: 55,
  six: 6
}

var secondObject = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  four: 4
}

returnObject = { four:55 }
```

Comment: Please explain your problem again ?

Comment: I want to return only those elements that object 1 has overwritten in object 2. Using the Ecmascript 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check what properties are present on both objects and difference in values, you can use `Object.entries` to convert the first object to array. Use `reduce` to loop thru the array, check and construct the new object.

```js
var firstObject = {
  one: 1,
  four: 55,
  six: 6
}

var secondObject = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  four: 4
}

var returnObject = Object.entries(firstObject).reduce((c, [k, v]) => {
  if (secondObject[k] !== undefined && v !== secondObject[k]) c[k] = v;
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(returnObject);
```

---

One liner code:

```
var returnObject = Object.entries(firstObject).reduce((c, [k, v]) => secondObject[k] !== undefined && v !== secondObject[k] ? Object.assign(c, {[k]: v}) : c, {})
```

Comment: It's great, but it does not work on empty strings.

var firstObject = {
  one: "one",
  four: 6,
  six: 9
}

var secondObject = {
  one: "",
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  four: 4
}

return {four: 6}

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries, filter and map new objects.

```js
var firstObject = {
    one: 1,
    four: 55,
    six: 6
}
var secondObject = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
    four: 4
}

var result = Object.assign({}, ...Object
    .entries(firstObject)
    .filter(([k, v]) => k in secondObject && secondObject[k] !== v)
    .map(([k, v]) => ({
        [k]: v
    }))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This solution is also great :)